# Difference Between Actor model and web service/Message Queue

Tags: c#, web-services, message-queue, actor

I am trying to understand concept of Actor Model. While I was looking at Akka.Net project, i thought I can also make it work the same functionality with using Web Services or Message Queues.

What are the main advantages of Actor Model Concept over Web services and Message Queues?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Actor Model is a modeling paradigm. Web Services and Message Queues are implementation technologies. So as you see those are completely different things. You may implement Actor Model with whatever techs you like. Just make sure it adheres to Actor Model fundamentals.

Actor Model deals with concurrent computation challenges and, as anything genius is fundamentally very simple.

See [Fundamental concepts](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Actor_model#Fundamental_concepts)